# Making different panels for createview and editview

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin, wagtail-snippet, wagtail-search

I'm currently working with a SnippetViewSet and I'm looking for a function or feature that provides different panels for editing and creation within this viewset. Specifically, I'm seeking a replacement for the edit_handler that was available in ModelAdmin. I'm interested in having distinct interfaces or sections for the creation of new snippets and for the editing of existing ones. Does anyone know if such functionality exists, and if so, how it can be implemented?

Any guidance or references to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

I've tried setting the form in get_context_data, but this approach didn't help.